# Use of a BSD License software in a thesis

Tags: bsd

I'm writing a master thesis and want to use software on BSD License to carry out my calculations. As I understand, I can use it freely since it's not even a commercial use. Just need somebody to confirm it. Also, should I disclose information about the license in my thesis?

Comment: I'm glad you are responsible enough to ask, even though the licensing doesn't apply in your case. Personal responsibility goes a long way towards improving any working environment, and can only help you in the future, like any good habit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, BSD-licensed code is free for anyone to use for any purpose.  You don't need to disclose the license in your thesis.

As @MadHatter pointed out, if you were to include the source of the program in your thesis, say as an appendix, you would need to include the license in that.

You should of course give credit as you would for any resource that you use, but that's an academic issue not a licensing issue.

Comment: If you were to include the source of the program in your thesis, say as an appendix, you would need to include the licence in that.  Otherwise, I agree with Glenn; +1 from me.

Comment: I would suggest citing it as you would cite some publication and mentioning the licence. This also makes it easier to see, that you used it and avoid the suspection that you try to use their code as your contribution in the thesis. It's okay to build something on top of something which is already there, but you need to make clear, which part was done by you.